# Razor pages client site validation not working

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I'm trying to use client-side validation in my razor pages app but it's not working for the views.

It does work on the register page that is located under the identity area.

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model Toolbox.Models.ProjectsModel.Assignment

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Nieuwe taak maken</h1>

<h4>Taak</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fase" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fase" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fase" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Maak nieuwe taak" class="btn btn-primary my-2"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">Terug</a>
</div>
```

**Assignment.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Toolbox.Interfaces;

namespace Toolbox.Models.ProjectsModel
{
    public class Assignment : IAssignment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Naam")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Fase { get; set; }

        public List<SubAssignment> SubAssignment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@using Toolbox
@using Toolbox.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

**_viewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Does anybody know how I need to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the *_ValidationScriptsPartial* file in the Razor page. Add the following to the bottom of the page/view:

```
@section scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: It worked! but Is it also possible to put this in the _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Sure! Just add the partial tag helper to the other script declarations that appear between the footer and the closing body tag.

Comment: It won't work when I put the tag helper in the _Layout.chtml. I have put the line(<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />) between </footer> and </body> just like you told me. Am I doing it wrong or is my code bugged?

Comment: Should have mentioned that the partial should be placed AFTER the reference to jQuery, because client-side validation depends on it.